# How to fix this error "HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection" in rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I Have created simple rails apps and I got error "HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection" that shown in rails admin when I want to post an Image.

this my code:

can anyone Help me to solve it ?

```
class ProductInvest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  has_many :pictures, through: :product
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures
  has_many :Product_invests
end

class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  has_many :Product_invests, through: :product
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your associations aren't setup correctly. Try this instead:

```
class ProductInvest < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
  has_many :pictures, through: :products
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :pictures
  belongs_to :product_invests
end

class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
  has_many :product_invests, through: :products
end
```

You can get more information here: [RubyGuides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)